# Derivative wrt to order of MacDonald function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to get the following result confirmed in Mathematica:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial\mathop{K_{\nu}}\nolimits\!\left(x\right)}{\partial\nu}%
\right|_{\nu=\pm\frac{1}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}\mathop{E_{1}}\nolimits%
\!\left(2x\right)e^{x},
$$
cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.38.E7. Here $K_{\nu}(z)$ denotes the [MacDonald function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25) and $E_1$ denotes the exponential integral.

However, Mathematica seems to be unaware of the above result. All I get for

```
D[BesselK[a, z], {a, 1}] /. a -> 1/2
```

is

$$
\text{BesselK}^{(1,0)}\left(\frac{1}{2},z\right).
$$

Can Mathematica be made more specific here?

Comment: `FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][1/2, z]]]` might be somewhat closer.

Comment: ...and of course the result in b.gatessucks's comment can be massaged into the required form.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by b.gatessucks, a preliminary application of `FunctionExpand[]` allows the confirmation of this identity:

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][1/2, z]] ==
             Sqrt[π/2] ExpIntegralE[1, 2 z] Exp[z]/Sqrt[z]]
   True

FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][-1/2, z]] ==
             -Sqrt[π/2] ExpIntegralE[1, 2 z] Exp[z]/Sqrt[z]]
   True
```

It should be noted that the particular form of the result in *Mathematica* uses $\frac1{\sqrt{z}}$ instead of $\sqrt{\frac1z}$, which corresponds to a different choice of branch cut on the negative real axis.

---

Only recently has a formula for $\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}K_\nu(z)$ for general values of $\nu$ been found; see e.g. [Brychkov's article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2016.1164156) and [this accompanying blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/05/16/new-derivatives-of-the-bessel-functions-have-been-discovered-with-the-help-of-the-wolfram-language/).